# MySQL doesn't prevent deletion of rows where primary key is associated with another table

Tags: mysql, sql

tested this on postgreSQL and it doesn't let me delete any row(primary key) associated with another table. Is MySQL different or is there is a way to do that here in Mysql?.

```sql
CREATE TABLE account (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE transaction (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    account_id BIGINT REFERENCES account(id)
);

INSERT INTO account (name) VALUES ('john');  //account_id = 1
INSERT INTO transaction (account_id) VALUES (1);

DELETE FROM account where id = 1;

);
```

when I delete an account row in account table, mySQL doesn't prevent the deletion of it.

Comment: Because ` REFERENCES ` Key are Present in account table so you can't delete it.

Comment: *tested this on postgreSQL and it doesn't let me delete any row(primary key) associated with another table.* You have not told the server that you associate something with something. You must define according FOREIGN KEY. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fe4b11828e57186aa8fb53d6f863876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example for MYSQL. You need add the foreign key with update and delete constrains. You can also read through the documents for more details. [Foreign Key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

```sql
CREATE TABLE account (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE transaction (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    account_id BIGINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES account(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

INSERT INTO account (name) VALUES ('john');
INSERT INTO transaction (account_id) VALUES (1);

DELETE FROM account where id = 1;

-- 18:32:14 DELETE FROM account where id = 1    Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`transaction`, CONSTRAINT `transaction_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) 0.039 sec
```

Comment: oh I didn't know I need to specify it, I though it's automatic like in postgreSQL